# Python : creating an array, weighed by sine function

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I can create an array of 100 **evenly spaced numbers** from 0 to 30 by doing -

```
theta = linspace(0,30,100)
```

Is it possible to get an array of 100 numbers from 0 to 30, which is not evenly spaced, but weighed by their sine function??

**EXPLANATION:** Here is a picture to give you a **vague** idea of what I want. The `theta` that I have defined, selects the points evenly (like the first picture). I want the array to be weighed with their sine function. As the numbers increase from 0 to 30, their sine(value) increases, so in my array I want to pick the higher numbers more frequently (like the second picture) -

[image]

Comment: Can you just confirm, when you say between 0 and 30 do you mean in degrees or radians?

Comment: I presume neither degrees nor radians. The OP seems to want numbers on a generic number line that *look kinda sine wavey* Almost like a function `np.sinespace` as opposed to `linspace` or `logspace`.

Comment: Simon, I mean degrees.

And yes, i wish there was a function like np.sinespace :) that would have worked just perfect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I've got your solution. It takes an originally linearly spaced array and takes the `sine` of it, it then returns the sines scaled to have the same end as the linear array.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def sinespace(m=90, n=10):
    x = np.linspace(0, m, n)
    s = np.sin(np.deg2rad(x))
    return (s/s[-1])*m

s = sinespace()
print(s)

plt.plot(s, np.ones_like(s), 'ro')
plt.show()
```

Note that, for a max of 30, the spacing is pretty similar to linearly spaced. This is because `theta` is linear with `sin(theta)` for small `theta` (and when `theta` is in radians, `theta ~= sin(theta)`). To show the "sinespacing" I've plotted it up to 90 degrees to make it more obvious.

[image]

Comment: This works!!! Yaayyy :) Thank you sssso much for this!! You should be in the python development team!!! Thanks a tonnes!

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear to me if you need something more specific, but you can create arbitrary arrays by starting with a linspace. For your "sin" case, try this:

```
theta = np.sin(np.linspace(0,np.pi/6,100)) * 30 / np.sin(np.pi/6)
```

Comment: @agenders3, this again gives me an evenly spaced array, just multiplied with it's sin function. I do not want the array to be evenly spaced on linear scale. So I do not want it to be multiplied by the Sine function, but weighed by it! (I hope I am making sense!)

Comment: @Panchi Sorry :/ I'm having trouble understanding what you mean. Maybe you can provide a little more context for your problem? The indices of the array will always be evenly spaced (such is the nature of an array), but you can change the spacing of the values as I have here.

Comment: If indices of an array are always evenly spaced, then I want it to be a sine space (just as you can have logspace, in place of linspace). Because python does not have a provision for that, I am fine with having a list too. But the values in that list (or array) should be **weighed** by the sine function. `Sin 0 = 0 `, so I should not have 0 in my list. It should pick up 100 values from 0 to 30, but not evenly... it should have ~10 values from 0-10, and then around 30 values from 10 to 20 and then around 60 values from 20 to 30.

Comment: I don't know what to tell you - my code does the same thing as the accepted answer. Glad you got it working, anyway!